Export access data to a word template using a query
I am trying to export data to a word template in the simplest way from a query
is it possible to do this as it seems it can only be done as an RTF file. I have a word template with the companies logo and I am trying to export new data where there has been a price change and will list all the items in that location regardless which one had a price change into the template which should create a new file but with the companies logo. The next step I think will be to create a macro that users can run. I have no VBA experiance but if thats the only way it can be done then I am all ears.
Very new to all this and just need to know what direction I should study
Thanks
SELECT Stocklist.[Part No], Stocklist.Description, Stocklist.[Retail Inc], Stocklist.[Bin No 1]
FROM Stocklist
WHERE (((Stocklist.[Bin No 1])=[Enter Bin Location:]));
When I right click this query I have the option to export it but the only option is a word RTF. is there a way to redirect it to a template or even a word document that already exists with a logo without deleting the logo
